# Why is GStreamer using dynamic RTP Type 96 instead of the static payload types PCMU or PCMA and how to change that?

Tags: networking, gstreamer, wireshark

I am trying to send audio data with a GStremer pipe trough my network. I wan´t to do it with UDP using the RTP protokoll using the payload number 0 or 1. If i set my pipe with those parameters (clock=8000) i hoped the right payload is used but when I check my packets with WireShark it shows me Dynamic-PayloadType-96.

My pipe lokks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=1,depth=8,width=8,rate=8000 ! audioresample ! rtpL8pay  ! udpsink host=172.16.20.15 port=5200
```

my packages in WireShark look then like this:

```
274  4.226028  172.16.20.131  172.16.20.15  RTP  1078   PT=DynamicRTP-Type-96, SSRC=0x1530A361, Seq=13125, Time=1708218536
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`rtpL8pay` packets PCM audio.

`rtppcmapay` packets PCMA audio.
`rtppcmupay` packets PCMU audio.

When having PCM input you you need to encode it to PCMA/PCMU respectively if you want to feed it to the appropriate payloaders.